# jQuery UI Tooltip effects are buggy

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

The problem I'm facing is on this page here:  http://opportunityfinance.net/test/default.aspx?id=6566

Basically, when you mouse over the images, sometimes the tooltip doesn't go away.  How can I be sure that all tooltips are hidden before showing the next tooltip (when they mouse over another image)??

Here's the code I am using:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    track: true,
    show: {
        effect: "puff",
        delay: 250
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        delay: 0
    }
});
```

Quite frankly, the `track: true` doesn't seem to work initially either, you have to move your mouse over the image to get it tracked to the mouse.

I have my HTML code set up like so (for each image on the page):

```
<div style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;" class="images" title="Click to Download {FileName}"><a href="{path to download file}"><img src="{image path}" /></a></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is remedy the 20 errors the W3 validator found: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fopportunityfinance.net%2Ftest%2Fdefault.aspx%3Fid%3D6566&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: lol, hehe... good observation, those were a pain the arse to get rid of on the main page of the site.  This site is about to be drupalized shortly, so the current state of it is not that important atm...  But noticing that jQuery UI tooltip is really annoying the hell out of me!  But I don't think that validation errors are interfering with jQuery UI's ability to handle tooltips TBH!

Comment: FYI:  Last I checked Google.com had 26 W3C Validation Errors... ;)